# JavaScript ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have an html file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AppName</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have a javascript file that contains this:

EDIT: included jQuery via npm, and it seems to have worked.

```
export function getData(arg, callback) {
    var $ = require('jQuery'); // This line was added via EDIT above.
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/get_data",
        data: {data: arg},
        success: callback
    });
}
```

When I go to my page and execute the function, I eventually get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.getData (http://localhost:1234/static/bundle.js:21665:6)
```

Based on the questions/answers I've seen on SOF, it seems like the solution was to include the jquery script in my html file.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: As per request, here is my react index.js file. The error is coming from within the searchApi.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';

import * as searchApi from './api/searchApi';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
        this.processData = this.processData.bind(this);
    }

    getData(data) {
        searchApi.getData(data, this.processData);
    }

    processData(payload) {
        console.log(payload);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBar getData={this.getData}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Your web console should be reporting an error loading the `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` file, which is why `$` is not defined. That's what you have to diagnose. (The link given above works for me, but clearly something somewhere isn't working for you.)

Comment: Alternately: Something is calling [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) that you're not aware of, which tells jQuery to release the `$` identifier.

Comment: I don't see any error in my console besides the one I posted. However, when looking at sources tab, I do not see jquery as a dependency. To my basic knowledge, it seems like I've imported it correctly?

Comment: check `jQuery` by typing on console. if present then check `jQuery == $`

Comment: The initial diagnosis is correct that jQuery is not defined. I assume I'm not correctly importing it via my html file?

Comment: You need to specify more of your code/HTML, as what you have provided does not produce this error.

Comment: try to open this http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js in new tab see if it's loading?

Comment: @trincot that is the extend of my HTML code. It is a react app where my index.js file import my api code like this: 

    import * as api from './api/dataApi';

ricky, I am able to see that.

Comment: Now you see your app should run fine

Comment: There is no trace of react in your question. Please add it. Add the relevant part of your `index.js`.

Comment: Edited to include relevant react code.

Comment: Since you are using cdn link of jquery .. Make sure you are connected with internet always

Comment: This might be caused by webpack (or whatever bundler you are using). Try to include JQuery inside of your js-file (via require; there is a npm package available)

Comment: @MichaelRitter, that seems to have worked, thanks!

Comment: I dont recommend to use `jQuery` with React .. if you need Ajax call , use the built-in `window.fetch` : `whatwg-fetch`